# Multiple sorting condition in results table, how to declare in pagination in model.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've question like how to apply multiple sorting conditions for particular results table?

Ex: if we have 20 records in a table consists of A,B,C(Name,price,date) columns

In those 10 records C has today date(It should be descending)  and in that 10 records - 5 records B has higher price(descending) and remaining 5  has lower price
and in those 5 records B which has higher price want those records in alpha name (Ascending )
Note: (On load) with out applying any sorting criteria's on Interface
thanks for your answers ..

Comment: I think it's not possible. Your user need to choose witch column will be sorted.

Comment: thanks for the answer, we managed to change the requirement..